# ¿Como puedo resolver la duplicidad de la información en la base de datos?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

El sistema que estoy diseñando tiene estas características:

1. Existe una tabla de usuarios llamada "usuarios".
2. Existe otra tabla de logs sobre las acciones que realizan los usuarios llamada "logs".

Dicho esto podemos decir que la relación entre la tabla "logs" y "usuarios" es que un log pertenece a un usuario y esto nos da la siguiente definición de tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT NULL,
    pass VARCHAR(70) DEFAULT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    apellidos VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT NULL,
    telefono VARCHAR(12) DEFAULT NULL,
    disabled TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0,
    fecha_incorporación DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE logs (
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_usuario INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    accion VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    fecha DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES usuarios(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

El problema que planteo es que si elimino de forma persistente un usuario, la relación con los registros de la tabla "logs" se rompe pero sin embargo sigo necesitando los datos: 'email', 'nombre', 'apellidos' e 'id' del usuario de alguna forma en un listado de logs, pensado únicamente para visualizar todos los movimientos de los usuarios en la web, sin importar las eliminaciones de registros.

Por tanto la única solución que se me ocurre es que en la tabla 'logs' creo los campos: 'email', 'nombre', 'apellidos' e 'id' del usuario y soluciono el problema duplicando la información.

Pero...¿Es una buena práctica?
¿Como lo haríais vosotrxs?
¿Como se normalizaría esta situación?

Comment: Has pensado en la posibilidad de no eliminar fisicamente los registros, sino crearte un campo llamado habilitado donde si su valor es 0 trataras el registro como si fisicamente lo hubieses eliminado pero en realidad esta alli.

Comment: ¿En qué quedamos, que vas a permitir borrar usuarios con delete o no?. Si vas a permitir borrar usuarios con delete tendrás que tomar una decisión sobre como se tiene que comportar con respecto a la tabla logs (echa un vistazo a on delete cascade,restrict,...: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). Si vas a usar tu campo disabled no habría ningún problema porque no estás borrando las entradas por lo que vas a poder seguir mostrando los logs de igual forma, lo que tendrás que pensar es que diferencia hay entre mostrar un log de un usuario normal de uno borrado

Comment: Yo te diría que la propuesta de U.Busto es la más adecuada. Dado que necesitas los datos de email, nombre, etc... genera una columna que indique si el usuario está activo o "borrado", de manera que puedas tener persistencia sin duplicidad

Comment: Debes considerar que "usuario deshabilitado" y "usuario eliminado" son dos cosas distintas. Lo que recomienda @U.Busto es tu mejor opción: un campo (estatus, por ejemplo) que pueda tomar 3 valores: 0=Activo, 1=Deshabilitado, 2=Eliminado. A partir de eso, cuando hagas una consulta a tu tabla usuarios sólo debes usar ese campo para filtrar los usuarios.